# Deep neural network diverges after convergence

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning

I implemented the A3C network in https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01783 in TensorFlow.

At this point I'm 90% sure the algorithm is implemented correctly. However, the network diverges after convergence. See the attached image that I got from a toy example where the maximum episode reward is 7.

When it diverges, policy network starts giving a single action very high probability (>0.9) for most states.

What should I check for this kind of problem? Is there any reference for it?

[image: This is from a toy example, the maximum episode reward is 7.]

Comment: Do you only have a reference to this?

Comment: @ArthurM. Reference to what?

Comment: Just thinking about whether someone else also has written already about this

Comment: @ArthurM. Maybe I didn't use the correct terms, but I couldn't find anything about this kind of problem.

Comment: I'm still getting into this topic, so could take a while. Apart this, how is the diagram to interpret? Y and X axis aren't labeled correctly.

Comment: Debugging neural networks isn't yet a routine task, but I'd expect a bit more effort. As I understand it, you implemented a new training algorithm, but did you verify that the network itself is reasonable? I.e. with any other known-good training algorithm? How well do those converge on comparable training data?

Comment: @MSalters I didn't implement a new algorithm, I'm using the one in the paper. I tried Atari Breakout game and it seemed to work correctly. I did tweak the network a little for my research problem (where the problem I ask about appears), but not in a way that would introduce bugs.

Comment: My guess is that it's some numerical stability problem. Do you see NaNs or zeros somewhere in your network?

Comment: I asked a friend who said "I bet his replay gets full". I know next to nothing about RL, but maybe that helps :)

Comment: @chris_anderson Thank you and your friend! I do not see any NaN or any kind of error during training. And I'm using the A3C algorithm, which does not use a replay buffer.

Comment: Is anything funny happening with your weight norm? If your weights shrink too much, your gradients will become innacurate

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov That could indeed be the problem, but I'm not sure how to pinpoint it... What should I look for? What are counted as "funny"? Thanks!

Comment: you can add weight norms to your tensorboard and check if accuracy loss correlates with them shrinking to zero (or exploding)

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Figure 1 of the original paper the authors say:

> For asynchronous methods we average over the best 5
>   models from 50 experiments.

That can mean that in lot of cases the algorithm does not work that well. From my experience, A3C often diverges, even after convergence. Carefull learning-rate scheduling can help. Or do what the authors did - learn several agents with different seed and pick the one performing the best on your validation data. You could also employ early stopping when validation error becomes to increase.